# How do you get your refund for a Greyhound bus refundable ticket in the US?

Tags: usa, greyhound, refunds

I purchased a Greyhound (USA) refundable bus ticket online. Decided later I will not make the trip. My e-mail confirmation includes the itinerary number, cost, times, etc. It mentions there will be a 20% charge which sounds reasonable. My credit card has already been charged.

How do I cancel the ticket order? I tried calling Greyhound customer service which told me to call the local bus station. The local bus station agent said they could not handle refunds over the phone. There seemed to be no reliable refund instructions online. Do I really need to physically travel to the bus station to get the refund? How do you get the refund?

Comment: Greyhound Australia or Canada? Or some other country?

Comment: In my case, the United States.

Comment: Anyway I drove to bus station hour away from me and they said it will go back on my card 48-72 hours I bought ticket for friend out of state online for will call but they won't be coming so I took suggested advice and it work seems like the problem is you can hardly get anyone on the phone to find out it took me forever to get answers this helps knowing if you did buy a ticket for someone else u have to go to the station for your refund. I I only needed the photo id and the confirmation number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I broke down and traveled to to the bus station. They were able to process my refund at the ticket window. I needed to provide **(1) photo id** and the  **(2) reference number** from the confirmation e-mail. The clerk printed the actual ticket, then I provided two signatures to complete the refund.

(I didn't realize a Greyhound bus ticket is NOT a reservation for a seat on the bus on that day like an airline ticket. Even though the confirmation e-mail lists the date and time of the departure and arrival, the ticket was valid for 1 year. I was thinking I need to get the refund before the scheduled date. According to the clerk, I could have processed the refund or used the bus ticket months after I originally planned to leave.)

Comment: Interesting, could you confirm that refundable tickets bought online are valid for any date (between an earliest and latest dates)? I checked a non-refundable online ticket I bought a while ago and it mentions "Ticket valid for schedule XXXX/<date> only".

Comment: @Vince Having traveled Greyhound a lot, I have some experience with this. Greyhound uses the schedule printed on your ticket for planning purposes, e.g. trying to avoid overbooking a schedule significantly. But you can change for free to any schedule that leaves _after_ that date, up to one year for a round trip ticket (and I think two or three months for a one-way ticket). This applies to full price tickets. What you can't usually do is change to a schedule _before_ that date and time, though I have had Greyhound do this once when that schedule was overbooked.

Answer (score 4):

If you following the [FAQ](http://www.greyhound.com/en/ticketsandtravel/refundsandexchanges.aspx#partiallyUsedTicket) it tells you how to obtain refund.  It states:

> To submit your request for a refund, please contact us in writing. Following are frequently asked questions about our refund policy.

The link in the FAQ gets you to the [contacts page](http://www.greyhound.com/en/contactus.aspx#refunds) which states that you need to contact the [Refunds Desk](http://www.greyhound.com/en/RefundsAndExchangesRequest.aspx) in writing to get your refund.

Comment: Thanks, I did try to submitting my ticket info using the Refunds and Exchanges Request form, but haven't received any response after 48 hours. The "contact us in writing" snail mail method sounds a bit archaic for an online ticket purchase, but I won't rule it out.

Comment: @JamesLawruk I've never known airlines or bus lines be very forthcoming or making it easy to get your money back.

Comment: @JamesLawruk Only 48 hours? I have had at least one airline refund that took 3 months to process.